# lazarus grids key-value pair

Tags: delphi, freepascal, lazarus, tstringgrid

In the lazarus (and also delphi probably) documentation about [grids](http://wiki.lazarus.freepascal.org/Grids_Reference_Page), we can find the next description for the `InsertRow` function:

```
Function InsertRow
    Inserts a row in the grid and sets
    the Key-Value pair. Returns the
    index of the newly inserted row.
```

What is this key-value pair?

Comment: As you can see at the link you provided, this function related to the TValueListEditor, something like object inspector in the IDE but much simpler. "Key-Value pair" is same to [TStrings Name-Value feature](http://lazarus-ccr.sourceforge.net/docs/rtl/classes/tstrings.values.html)

Comment: @Abelisto - ok, so a key=value pair is added to the grid line? or to line collection of the grid? And what are the key and the value?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is related to the TValueListEditor, and not grids in general. The `TValueListEditor` is similar in appearance to the Delphi *Object Inspector*. For brevity, I'll refer to it as *VLE* in the text below.

`TValueListEditor.InsertRow` takes three parameters:

```
function InsertRow(const KeyName: string; const Value: string; 
  Append: Boolean): Integer;
```

The `keyname` parameter is the name of the key (the left column of the VLE). `Value` is the key value (the right column of the VLE). This is stored in the same manner as the `TStrings` key=value pairs in the `Strings` property. For instance, calling it using `InsertRow('Testing', '123', False)` would store `Testing=123`.

`Append` merely controls whether the new entry is added before or after any already selected item in the VLE. If the VLE is empty, it has no effect.

For more information, see the [Delphi VCL help](http://docwiki.embarcadero.com/Libraries/XE8/en/Vcl.ValEdit.TValueListEditor.InsertRow)